# When I run my Flex app, a different, older version is run?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

When I hit the run button in Flash Builder 4, an older version of my app is being run. I can't for the life of me work out why this is happening. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you save? Did you remember to publish?

Comment: Do a Project clean.  Clear your browser cache.

Comment: I did a clean, and cleared the cache. But now, nothing is coming up when the browser loads. It's literally an empty screen. When I view the source for the page, it all looks correct, and it's loaded the Talk.swf (Talk is my project name), but nothing is loading in the browser. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it is very common for me to run into this problem if I change code and compile an app while an active debugging session is running.  So, be sure to always stop all debugging sessions before recompiling the app--it will happen every time you save if you have "Build automatically" selected.

IF the app won't change.  Turn off the debugging session; shut down your browser completely--not just the window w/ your app--and then clean the project.

That always addresses the issue for me.

If the browser doesn't appear to be showing the swf after you take these actions; that is odd.  Try loading the SWF directly, not the enclosing HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an errors in your code?

If you've turned on the "Always launch without asking" option (when the "Errors in Workspace" dialog box is shown) then it would use the previously successful compilation.

Can you browse to Talk.swf directly, and does that work?

If so, then it'll be a HTML or JavaScript error in your wrapper file. Try loading it in FireFox and looking at the error console.