# flex 4 release changes to application are not showing up

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, flex4

I just took over a clients flex project and I can't get the app to reflect even a simple trace statement.
Before I took over, the project was last successfully built using the Flash Builder Beta 2 environment/sdk. I have the latest release version of Flash Builder 4.

Upon importing the project into FB4, I got a ton of errors.  Most of them mostly because of the changes made to the sdk from beta2 to release.

Some of the things I corrected:
- mx namespace from library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo to library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx
- video player skinning:  a lot of the state names for the video player component had been changed, more required states had been added.  also there were other video related component and property names that had to be updated.

But I fixed all that and the application was finally able to compile (although with some warnings mostly of the duplicate variable type)

The only thing now is that whatever change I make to the project doesn't get reflected in the build (debug or release).  I changed existing traces, added additional traces. Nothing shows up.  I even removed the applicationComplete property in the main.mxml.  Everything still ran like nothing changed.

Also I can't seem to debug the app.  Whenever I try to debug.. flash builder says..
"Swf Application doesn't contain the required debugging information ... "

Anyone have any idea how I need to even begin tackling all this?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the project associated with the right SDK?

Comment: i believer so.. as i said.. the project was last built with the beta 2 sdk.
since that build is no longer available for download.. I have no option but to import it to the release build and make the necessary fixes, and I've successfully gotten rid of all the errors. 
I just can't seem to make any changes to the app anymore.. I even just deleted an enormous block of code (while taking care of dependencies), and the app compiled and worked as if no change had been made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the input everyone. i solved the issue by setting up up a new project and copying the code over.  something must have have screwed up in the  upgrading of the flex application and handing off the code among multiple developers. 
simply creating a new project and copying the code over seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well the most obvious cause of this kind of problem is that you are not running the correct SWFs after you compile. For example you compile to C:\project\bin-debug but you instead are opening C:\project2\bin-debug\main.swf in your browser. Or perhaps you are compiling to C:\project\bin-debug, but you are opening http://project/main.swf in your browser.

Unfortunately since it's a specific configuration problem, I can't tell you exactly how to fix it without seeing exactly how your project is set up & where you are running it from on your own PC.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:
[When I run my Flex app, a different, older version is run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707160/when-i-run-my-flex-app-a-different-older-version-is-run/2708514#2708514)

> I find it is very common for me to run into the problem if I change code and compile an app while an active debugging session is running. So, be sure to always stop all debugging sessions before recompiling the app--it will happen every time you save if you have "Build automatically" selected.
>
> If the app won't change. Turn off the debugging session; shut down your browser completely--not just the window w/ your app--and then clean the project.
>
> That always addresses the issue for me.
>
> If the browser doesn't appear to be showing the swf after you take these actions; that is odd. Try loading the SWF directly, not the enclosing HTML page.